# Is there a way to get report on IRM enabled Libraries and lists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I am not able to find right PowerShell or a way to get a report on IRM enabled libraries and lists.
What I am looking for is to get list of Libraries and Lists that has been enabled with "IRM policies" from entire Farm. This is for SharePoint 2013.
I would like to capture all the key properties of IRM settings for each of these libraries and lists across the Farm.
It's been bit struggle to get these details as we want understand in-depth before moving to online.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please don’t take me wrong. I am not looking for how to activate it. We already activated and using right now in SP2013. What I am looking is to get a Report on list of libraries and lists which has been enable by IRM.  Hope I am clear here.

Answer (score -1):

Before your organization can IRM-protect SharePoint lists and libraries, you must first activate **the Rights Management service** for your organization. To learn how see **[Activating Azure Rights Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/activate-service)**.

You can refer to **[this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/apply-irm-to-a-list-or-library?view=o365-worldwide)** to enable IRM for SharePoint document libraries and lists.

For more information, please see this article "**[Set up Information Rights Management (IRM) in SharePoint admin center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/set-up-irm-in-sp-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide)**".

Comment: Please don’t take me wrong. I am not looking for how to activate it. We already activated and using right now in SP2013. What I am looking is to get a Report on list of libraries and lists which has been enable by IRM. Hope I am clear here.